# How do I add Views to a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Every example/tutorial I've come across just adds Strings to ListViews, but I want to add inflated Views.  I've tested the inflated view and it looks fine if I add it to some ViewGroup like a RelativeLayout using addView().  But adding the inflated view to the ListView just displays it in the form of text:

[image]

```
ArrayList<View> friend_request_items = new ArrayList<View>();  //a list containing the items we want to add 

ListView friend_request_list = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.friend_request_list );

ArrayAdapter<View> friend_request_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<View>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, friend_request_items);

friend_request_list.setAdapter( friend_request_adapter );

//friend_template is just my own xml file containing the view I'm inflating
View friend_request_item = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.friend_template, null);

friend_request_items.add( friend_request_item ); 
friend_request_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think the problem is the layout I'm passing into the adapter, but I don't know what to change it to (or if this is even the solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every example/tutorial I've come across just adds Strings to ListViews

There are other examples out there, though you are unlikely to find examples of what you are proposing.

> I want to add inflated Views

A `ListAdapter` returns "inflated Views" from its `getView()` method. It is up to you to determine exactly how it does that.

Moreover, the point behind a `ListView` is to be able to recycle list row `Views`, as lists can be large and rows are expensive in terms of heap space. Your code appears to create all the row views up front, which is only suitable for small data sets.

> But adding the inflated view to the ListView just displays it in the form of text

When `ListView` calls `getView()` on  `ArrayAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter` gets the model for the desired row, calls `toString()` on it, and pours that into a `TextView` identified by your other constructor parameters (in this case, a `TextView` formatted as defined in `android.R.id.simple_list_item_1`).

> I think the problem is the layout I'm passing into the adapter, but I don't know what to change it to (or if this is even the solution).

First, I strongly encourage you to reconsider your original mindset ("I want to add inflated Views"). Bear in mind that you have to deal with configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation, locale changes) and process termination, and your "inflated Views" go away in either case. A `ListView` and `ListAdapter` are designed to convert *model data* into appropriate visual representations, and do so in a memory-efficient fashion.

That being said, if you are utterly convinced in your overall approach, you will need to create a custom `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` subclass, where in `getView()` you return the desired "inflated View" for a given `position`.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarifications.  I thought there'd be a super simple way to just add the Views I inflate to the default ArrayAdapter, but I guess I have to make an entire new class just to implement that getView() method. Oh also, regarding the example I provided, that's not my actual code.  I just made the example as simple as possible so people wouldn't have to look at unnecessary code :) I promise I am not creating the row views up front.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice tutorial using a custom ArrayAdapter and custom xml layout [Using lists in Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).
You should subclass an ArrayAdapter and inflate a row inside a getView method, it is a common and efficient solution, and instead of passing a view as a generic parameter of a list, you should pass a data class, for Example `ArrayAdapter<FriendRequest>` or something like that

```
public class FriendRequestsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendRequest> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public FriendRequestsAdapter(Context context, List<FriendRequest> requests) {
    super(context, R.layout.friend_request_row, requests);
    this.inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_request_row, parent, false);
    }

    FriendRequest item = getItem(position);
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    return convertView;
}
```

}